# How to set a custom class instance to Button.Content property via XAML markup?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF Application I created some `Class1`:

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {

    class Class1 {
        public override string ToString() {
            return "Hello, WPF!";
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to set the instance of this class to `Button.Content` property in the XAML markup. How can I do it?

I try to do it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="246,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
            <Button.Content>
                <!-- ERROR: This is wrong syntax: -->
                <Object x:Class="WpfApplication1.Class1"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What is right syntax for this case?

Comment: Class1  must be public

Comment: @levent: No, it works without `public` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and it worked.

```
<Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="246,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
    <local:Class1 />
</Button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A better practice is to implement *`INotifyPropertyChanged`* and a property which will be binded in xaml. something like that:

```
 class Class1 {
private string _Text;
            public Class1(){
           _Text = this.ToString();
        }
        public override string ToString() {
            return "Hello, WPF!";
        }
    }

public string Text
        {
            get{return _Text;}
            protected set { _Text = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
```

In XAML do:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I hope that provide a solution to your issue.